# Comparison of two List in Java and displaying the difference between two List in tabular format in JSP using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I have two Arraylist namely-

```
    List<java_test> one=new ArrayList<java_test>();
    List<java_test> two=new ArrayList<java_test>();
```

I **have two methods** which returns the defined ArrayList values individually.
the first arraylist i.e **one has more values as compared to second arraylist i.e. two.**

Now I want to

> compare the values of both the array list and find out there
>   difference

and display that in tabular format.Moreover as the fi**rst Arraylsit one** has more values **as compared to two**.So when there is only values of one arraylsit **0** should be displayed as there difference.

**EDIT-1**

I tried to achieve calculate difference as-

```js
 public LinkedHashMap < String, List < Double >> diff() {
   for (int i = 0; i < one.size() && i < two.size(); i++) {
     Comaprision refObj = one.get(i);
     Comaprision stObj = two.get(i);
     Double x = refObj.getBeam_current();
     Double y = stObj.getBeam_current();


     x = refObj.getBeam_energy();
     y = stObj.getBeam_energy();
     comparing(x, y);

     x = refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag1_rb();
     y = stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag1_rb();
     comparing(x, y);

     x = refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag2_rb();
     y = stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag2_rb();
     comparing(x, y);

     x = refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag3_rb();
     y = stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag3_rb();
     comparing(x, y);

     x = refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag4_rb();
     y = stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag4_rb();
     comparing(x, y);


     dif.put("", z);


   }
   return dif;
 }

 public List < Double > comparing(Double x1, Double y1) {

   if ((x1 > y1)) {

     z.add(x1 - y1);
     System.out.println("value of z is" + z);
   } else {
     z.add(y1 - x1);

   }


   return z;
 }
```

The output I receive is-
[image]
But It does not give correct difference.Whats the mistake I have done.?

Comment: What exactly is your problem when trying to accomplish this?

Comment: as you are saying `one` arraylist has more elements than `two`, will this not fail with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`?

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood your question correctly. What you want to do is print the difference if both the array list has values for same index or print zero when only one array list has value for the same index.

for this there are two possibilities.

If your array list only contains non-zero value. You could change the condition of for loop as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++) // since you have already specified first array list is larger than the second.
```

Then change the comparing function as follows:

```
public List < Double > comparing(Double x1, Double y1) {

 if(y1 == 0)
 {
    z.add(0);
 }
 else
 if ((x1 > y1)) {

 z.add(x1 - y1);
 System.out.println("value of z is" + z);
 } else {
 z.add(y1 - x1);

 }


 return z;
 }
```

If your arraylist contains zero values. I would suggest doing something like this

```js
 public LinkedHashMap < String, List < Double >> diff() {
   for (int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++) {
     if(i < two.size()){
     Comaprision refObj = one.get(i);
     Comaprision stObj = two.get(i);
     Double x = refObj.getBeam_current();
     Double y = stObj.getBeam_current();


     x = refObj.getBeam_energy();
     y = stObj.getBeam_energy();
     comparing(x, y);

     x = refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag1_rb();
     y = stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag1_rb();
     comparing(x, y);

     x = refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag2_rb();
     y = stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag2_rb();
     comparing(x, y);

     x = refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag3_rb();
     y = stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag3_rb();
     comparing(x, y);

     x = refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag4_rb();
     y = stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag4_rb();
     comparing(x, y);


     
     }
     else{
        for(i=0; i<(the number of variables your comparing in the if condition above); i++)
        {
        z.add(0.0);
        }
     }
   }
   dif.put("", z);
   return dif;
 }

 public void comparing(Double x1, Double y1) {

   if ((x1 > y1)) {

     z.add(x1 - y1);
     System.out.println("value of z is" + z);
   } else {
     z.add(y1 - x1);

   }
 }
```

Comment: You understood correctly. But there is one problem in **else{dif.put("",0.0);
}**.It shows an exception **The method put(String, List<Double>) in the type HashMap<String,List<Double>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, double)**.How to rectify it.

Comment: I have pasted my output.After doing as mentioned above, correct difference is not shown.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++) {
     if(i < two.size()){     ...} I think there is some problem in this loop ,as when i becomes greater then the size of i then what?? and  as we know one is greater than two.So i has to become greater than two.

Comment: u need to add one more for loop inside the else condition as i have added.

Comment: Now at **Comaprision stObj = two.get(i)** line,index out of bound is shown as two List has less values as compared to one List.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve that problem. But I haven't tried it yet on an object using a self-written class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();


    /*Put values to both lists*/
    list1.add("John");
    list1.add("Doe");

    list2.add("John");
    list2.add("Doe");

    /*Add other objects to list2. This will be the differences*/
    list2.add("Jane");
    list2.add("Roe");


    System.out.println("Printing two lists before retaining differences");
    System.out.println("list1: "+list1);
    System.out.println("list2: "+list2+"\n");

    System.out.println("Similarities removed. Differences stored to list2");
    list2.removeAll(list1);
    System.out.println("differences: "+list2);
}
```

}

Comment: no,I have double type values in my list.I have to subtract the values from both the lists and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your algorithm in doing the comparison is right. For example if x1 = -1 and x2 = 5:  `x2 - x1 = 5 - (-1)` = `5 + 1` = `6`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>(); //where result will be stored

    //Load with values
    list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Double[]{3.0,-5.0,7.0,-9.0,11.0,-13.0}));
    list2.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Double[]{1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0}));
    System.out.println("list1: "+list1);
    System.out.println("list2: "+list2);

    for(int i=0; i<list1.size() && i<list2.size(); i++) {
        double d1 = list1.get(i);
        double d2 = list2.get(i);

        //If d1 is greater than d2, do d1 minus d2 otherwise do d2 minus d1
        //I don't know if that is really the purpose of doing the difference in your code
        //Store result to result list
        result.add( d1>d2 ? d1-d2 : d2-d1);

    }

    //Print the result
    System.out.println("result: "+result);
}
```

Comment: My arraylist does not contains negative values and my list are of object type as mentioned in my question.

Comment: OK then. So just be sure that both lists have the same size. And if for example there is one index in the first that has no value the you must supply it with 0. That way you can be sure that the size of both lists are the same.

Comment: My list can be of same size and I can;t supply 0 also,resultset from sql query is added into the list.

Comment: OK understood. So where do you think the results are incorrect, backend or frontend? You can do a System.out.println() on backend Java class.